# How do I get the value an NSManagedObjectID was created from

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

Let's say the `[managedObjectID URIRepresentation]` uri is:

```
x-coredata://ABCDEF/Post/p1234567
```

At first, I thought I could use `[[objectID URIRepresentation] lastPathComponent]`, but this returns

```
p1234567
```

instead of just `1234567`. I can slice off the p, but this seems like not the proper way of doing things. Is there a better way?

Comment: For now I will use `[[[managedObjectID URIRepresentation] lastPathComponent] substringFromIndex:1]`

Comment: What are you trying to do? The URI representation of a managed object ID is only meant to be stored somewhere and passed to the `managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation` method of `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to get the `NSManagedObjectID` again. This can be used to query the actual object this refers to. Any part of that URI string is meaningless by itself, even if it happens to look like information from your model objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public API to obtain that value. The structure of an NSManagedObjectID is dependent upon the persistent store type for which it is generated (SQLite, XML, etc.).

I am also curious why you need it though, as its not actually possible to query for a managed object using only that number.